# A function that always returns the same vector

Tags: c++, function, static

I am trying to write a utility function that will return a vector. The returned vector will always have the same entries. I am using it to filter an enum (`Directions`) so that clients can obtain the desired subset.

Here is an example of how I hope to approach the problem:

```
std::vector<Directions> horizontalDirections()
{
    static std::vector<Directions> toReturn;
    if (toReturn.size() == 0)
    {
        toReturn.push_back(Left);
        toReturn.push_back(Right);
    } 
    return toReturn;
}
```

Is this the correct way to go about it?

Comment: In some cases the vector might be very large. This is why I want to avoid pushing everything into the vector if I don't need to.

Comment: You could return a `const vector` by reference

Answer (score 8):

The way you do it works. But I would return a `const` reference, so that a copy could be avoided if not needed:

```
const std::vector<Directions>& horizontalDirections();
```

Also, if you are using C++11, your implementation could be abbreviated as:

```
const std::vector<Directions>& horizontalDirections()
{
    static std::vector<Directions> toReturn({Left, Right});
    return toReturn;
}
```

If using C++11, you could go even further and declare you `horizontalDirections` as a global `const vector` instead of a function:

```
const std::vector<Directions> horizontalDirections({Left, Right});
```

Comment: Note the global object version may contribute to a Static Initialization Order Fiasco.  (The function version can only be involved in a Destruction Order Fiasco.)

Answer (score 5):

That's basically the right idea.  I would return by reference to avoid copying the vector.  And you can make the body much more legible using a C++11 initializer-list style:

```
const std::vector<Directions>& horizontalDirections() {
    static const std::vector<Directions> toReturn = {
        Left,
        Right
    };
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Additional advantage is that you get thread safety for free if it's a concern. Initialization of static variables is thread safe, later changing them (i.e. pushing into it) wouldn't be. Always something worth considering with static variables if multi threading is of any concern at all.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it as a function at all, but as a constant like this at a global scope:

```
const std::vector<Direction> horizentalDirections = {Left, Right};
```

that's what constants are made for.